# combine several functions in Python

Tags: python, oop

I do RSS parsing and get news from news headlines

```
def print_headlines_test(rss_dict):
    for key,url in rss_dict.items():
        feed = feedparser.parse(url)

    headlines = []

    allheadlines = []

    for newsitem in feed['items']:
        headlines.append(newsitem['title'])

    for key,url in rss_dict.items():
        allheadlines.extend(headlines)
```

Then i'm saving this to csv and read df:

```
def write_and_read():
    header = ['Tittle' , 'Desc'] 

    with open('news.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile: 

        writer.writerow(i for i in header) 

    for a  in zip(allheadlines):
        writer.writerow((a))


    df = pd.read_csv('news.csv')
```

Then i'm searching news by certain targets (t & t2):

```
t = 'word1|word2|word3'
t2 = 'word3|word4|word5'
```

And making dataframe of this:

```
def certain_words(t, t2):
    result = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(t, na=False,
                                    flags = re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)).any(axis=1)
    result2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(t2, na=False,
                                    flags = re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)).any(axis=1)
    df[result&result2]
```

So, my input values is `rss_dict` (dictionary of rss with format `{'rss-name':'rss-link'}` and two targets (`t,t2`)

Now my question. How i should combine all of this functions to something (`function` or maybe `class`) in order to set these three values `(rss_dict, t, t2)` and so that my code runs immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class with all these functions included inside as follows:

```
class News:
    def __init__(self,rss_dict,t, t2):
        rss_dict=self.rss_dict
        t=self.t
        t2=self.t2

    def print_headlines_test(self):
        for key,url in self.rss_dict.items():
            feed = feedparser.parse(url)

        headlines = []

        allheadlines = []

        for newsitem in feed['items']:
            headlines.append(newsitem['title'])

        for key,url in self.rss_dict.items():
            allheadlines.extend(headlines)
        self.allheadlines=allheadlines

    def write_and_read(self):
        header = ['Tittle' , 'Desc'] 

        with open('news.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile: 

            writer.writerow(i for i in header) 

        for a  in zip(self.allheadlines):
            writer.writerow((a))


        df = pd.read_csv('news.csv')

    def certain_words(self):
        result = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(self.t, na=False,
                                        flags = re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)).any(axis=1)
        result2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(self.t2, na=False,
                                        flags = re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)).any(axis=1)
        df[result&result2]
```

You should pass the parameters by creating an object of the class and the functions has to be called using the created object for them to run

Comment: you mean i should create an object like `a=News()` and then run functions like `a.print_headlines_test(my_rss_dict)` ?

Comment: i think you forgot about to add arguments `self` in parameters in `print_headlines_test` and `certain words`, this should be `def print_headlines_test(self):` and `def certain_words(self):` isn't it?

Comment: `a=News(my_rss_dict,t,t2)`with their values passed to the constructor (and not the function)and then run the functions `a.print_headlines_tes()`

Comment: first function `a.print_headlines_test()` returns me `allheadlines` - this is right. But second one can't find `allheadlines` and work with this so i got this error `name 'allheadlines' is not defined`. i think it's because my `allheadlines` inner `print_headlines_test` and other function `write_and_read` didn't see it, how can i fix it?

Comment: Once you are done creating the `allheadlines` make it a global variable by doing `self.allheadlines=allheadlines` inside that function. And use this `self.allheadlines` in the `write_and_read ` function instead of just using `allheadlines`

Comment: added `self.allheadlines=allheadlines` to `__init__` and changed all of `allheadlines` to `self.allheadlines` in `print_headlines_test` and `write_and_read`. Is it right? But i've got error `name 'allheadlines' is not defined` and link to this line `self.allheadlines = allheadlines`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209365/discussion-between-raghul-raj-and-germanjke).